# Database connection and save data from c++ program to MySQL

Tags: c++, database

I never had to deal with database, therefore, sorry in advance!

I was asked to create a database for a project and store data output from a c++ program into the database. I informed on Google about databases, and I came across with MySQL, and in particular database connection. As far as I understood, in the first place a database has to be created (for example with MySQL), and once data are inserted, it’s possible to access to them. However, it’s not totally clear what is possible to achieve with such a connection and how to save data from a c++ program into the database directly.

Based on what I read on the net, these should be related, is it right? I would really need some help, example or clarification about these two questions.  Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I think you should read more about databases in general. Then you can learn the syntax to connect to databases and work with the data. Following links may be useful:

https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/database-programming-with-cc.html

https://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/article.php/3478051

Comment: `how to save data from a c++ program into the database directly` If you're using SQL database, such as MySQL, then it's achieved (as virtually any other task) by executing SQL statement (such as INSERT INTO ...). So basically your question splits into two: 1) How to connect to DB engine - that depends on what engine/library/tools you use; and 2) How do I use SQL - start with reading a couple of books about it ;-)

Comment: Imho this question is too broad. You should start reading about databases and how they work. Using them in C++ is a way later step. Learn how they work, how you add databases and tables, how to add and alter data, etc. Therefore there are many documents on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I definitely will read in detail about MySQL and database. However, just to have a clue about this, the basic idea is, if I understood well: create a database (MySQL for example), connect the c++ application to the database and include whatever is needed, and use the MySQL syntax to insert data and work with the database. Please let me know if this is wrong, thanks again for your helps!

Answer (score 0):

First you should create DB and tables.
You can do it in each DB IDE wizards, or you can write it in a script.

So here are scrypt for MySQL

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db --this create DB called test_db
```

I guess you should store a message and a timestamp so a possible table (In MySQL) will be:

```
USE test_db -- from now on the script using test_db unless specified explicit DB
--creating table with id, mmessage and timestamp 
CREATE TABLE output_table ( 
   msg_ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   msg VARCHAR(max),
   msg_TS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

In the above table you only need to give the message since all the rest are filled automatically. So Insert into the table command may look like this:

```
INSERT INTO output_table (msg) values ('this is a message')
```

When you want to check the whole table you run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM output_table
```

Now you need to connect this code to your c++ code: 
Generally, you'll need to know db name, user name and password in manner to connect to DB.

You can use ODBC + MySQL ODBC Connector. It is better since you are not limitted in your c++ to a specific DB. If you are sure you will use only MySQL you can use also [MySQL C++ Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) directly. Anyway, both will give you option to run SQL commands on your DB.

- [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) you can fine MySQL c++ connector sample
- [HERE](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/21309-cpp-with-odbc-open-database-connectivity/) you can find ODBC sample.